# проблемы с воспроизведением flv видео

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется довольно много видео файлов в формате flv. Выложил их на сайт для просмотра используя video.js плеер, проблем не замечал, немного притормаживали, но подумал что это из за того что файлы большие. После тестов стали говорить, что у кого то вообще не воспроизводятся, у кого то не прокручиваются. Проверил на всех браузерах и заметил, что только на Опере такие проблемы иногда. На Андройд телефоне вообще не воспроизводятся...

Стал гуглить и нашел, что формат flv вообще не годится для видео стриминга? Это правда? Есть ли какой то выход чтоб их бес проблем проигрывало на всех браузерах и телефонах? Перекодировать их все не вариант. Видео десятки по нескольку часов, а компьютер слабоват...

Comment: http://professorweb.ru/my/html/html5/level3/3_2.php .... вроде `mp4` самый популярный

Comment: video.js лишь обертка к api, и сам по себе не будет конвертировать видео.
Как ни крути, если хотите кроссбраузерности, то стоит смотреть в сторону конвертации в наиболее популярные форматы. Я бы даже сказал, что использование нескольких форматов сразу, является обычным делом.  Если говорить о конвертации, то возможно вам это подойдет, https://cloudconvert.com/, хотя большого опыта испольования не было.